# Меню поста разваливается на две строчки

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, дизайн

Если в пункте меню присутствует пробел, то меню расползается на две строчки:

> [image: Screenshot]

В этой области есть три блока: меню, автор последней правки, автор поста. Однако меню ограничено по ширине, даже если правок нет. В идеале меню должно располагаться над блоками с авторами, если ему не хватает отведённых 240 пикселей. И, как минимум, у пунктов меню должен быть запрещён перенос слов (не должно возникать "удалить \n (2)").

Comment: Связанный вопрос (про ту же область верстки): [На удаленном вопросе ломается верстка](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/973)